# Displaying user input from an Android application on webpage in real time?

Tags: android, node.js, ubuntu, socket.io

I have created an `Android application` that takes basic input from users. I would like to display this input in `real time` on a webpage.

What are the best options to allow me to do so?

I was considering saving the data on an `Ubuntu server` that is running `NodeJS`, then reading and displaying the input using `socket.io` on a webpage?

Comment: Look into MeteorJS. It is a real time web framework. If you post updates from your android app to the MongoDB that MeteorJS uses, the data will change in real time on the web app as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Google Analytics rather than writing this yourself? GA has an event tracking api that's easy to add to your app. The data is displayed in real time on their Web client. Users have lots of flexibly with how to view the data, and can create their own custom reports.